# VB.net: How do I link XAML VB files?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, xaml

How do I link the VB MainWindow.XAML and my calculatorWindow.XAML together.

I have this code in my MainWindow.XAML file

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
    <Controls:WindowCommands>
        <Button Content="Information" Click="ButtonClicked"/>
        <Button Content="Calculator" Click="ButtonClicked2"/>
    </Controls:WindowCommands>
</Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
```

I want to add the code that links the MainWindow.XAML to the calculator.xaml.vb via the `ButtonClicked2`, how do I do that?

Comment: You mean you want to open the calculator view when you click on a button?

Comment: Yes when i click on a button i want to open the 'calculatorWindow' window. Which i will then make. But i have to first link it so i can access the window view, then i make the calculator app. Any help on the code i should input into the ButtonClicked? Or wherever it should be?